# Calculate the min and max time with disconnection intervals SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I need to calculate the time between two dates; the problem is that I have the data of x-person in two rows starting at day 1 at x time and finishing day 2 at x time and start over again the day 2 at x time until day 3 at x time...

So what I need is to determine the duration of each person per day.

Hope you guys can help me!!!

Thank you in advance.

I´ve tried some options but I can't get the result I'm looking for.

```
-- Table example

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(person varchar(10), startDate DATE, startTime TIME(0), endDate DATE, endTime TIME(0))

INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 'PERSON A' person, '2019-06-06' startDate, '02:14:00' startTime, '2019-06-06' endDate, '06:00:00' endTime

INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 'PERSON A' person, '2019-06-06' startDate, '22:00:00' startTime, '2019-06-07' endDate, '06:00:00' endTime

SELECT * FROM  @tbl -- > This would be the table example
```

The expected result would be

First_Row = (2019-06-06 06:00:00 - 2019-06-06 02:14:00) => 03:46:00

Second_RowA = (2019-06-06 22:00:00 - 2019-06-06 24:00:00) => 02:00:00

Second_RowB = (2019-06-07 02:14:00 - 2019-06-07 00:00:00) => 02:14:00 because the remaining time is being calculated by the first row between

So finally the result would be:

First_Row + Second_RowA + SecondRowB = 08:00:00

UPDATE:

The answer didn't work for what I need to do, but I know the question is a little tricky (sorry my English is not good), I'll try to explain better so here I go:

I have data for login and logout of call center agents, these agents have a work shift from 22 to 06, so what I need to calculate is the min of loginTime and max of logOutTime, but this is where it becomes complex, because there are cases where an agent is disconnected during that time range, then another login event is created in the database on the same day where another shift begins and so on.

So my question is: how can I determine the min and max I need, to be displayed only once per agent and per date?

Here's the data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(agentId VARCHAR(10), position VARCHAR(10), loginDate DATE, loginTime TIME(0), logoutDate DATE, logoutTime TIME(0))

INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230025', '2019-06-03', '21:59:00', '2019-06-04', '06:00:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230025', '2019-06-04', '21:59:00', '2019-06-04', '23:30:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230025', '2019-06-04', '23:31:00', '2019-06-05', '06:01:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230038', '2019-06-05', '21:59:00', '2019-06-06', '02:13:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230038', '2019-06-06', '02:14:00', '2019-06-06', '06:00:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230037', '2019-06-06', '22:00:00', '2019-06-07', '06:00:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230038', '2019-06-07', '21:59:00', '2019-06-08', '00:53:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230038', '2019-06-08', '00:53:00', '2019-06-08', '06:00:00'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT '311338', '230038', '2019-06-09', '22:00:00', '2019-06-10', '06:09:00'

SELECT agentId
    ,position
    ,(CAST(loginDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(loginTime AS DATETIME)) loginTime
    ,(CAST(logoutDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(logoutTime AS DATETIME)) logoutTime
  FROM @tbl
```

Result for agentId 311338 would be:

Day 2019-05-06:
minLogin = 2019-06-05 21:59:00.000
maxLogout = 2019-06-06 06:00:00.000

Day 2019-06-06:
minLogin = 2019-06-06 22:00:00.000
maxLogout = 2019-06-07 06:00:00.000

Day 2019-06-07:
minLogin = 2019-06-07 21:59:00.000
maxLogout = 2019-06-08 06:00:00.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to convert the date and time pairs into `DateTime` values, calculate the differences, total the values and convert the result to a string.

Note that your sample data has an incorrect `endTime` in the second row.

Your question is a bit unclear, but it seems that you only want the final sum. There is no need to break rows into daily intervals as you have proposed (Second_RowA and Second_RowB), you can simply take the difference and sum it.

Since `Time` is limited to values less than 24 hours I have taken the differences in seconds, summed them, and converted the result to a string that may have a number of hours greater than 24. You could modify the code to format the result as "ddd hh:mm:ss" if you like.

There are several `select` statements commented out at the end of the code sample. You can replace the final `select` with one of the others to see the intermediate results of the CTE.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(person varchar(10), startDate DATE, startTime TIME(0), endDate DATE, endTime TIME(0))

INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 'PERSON A' person, '2019-06-06' startDate, '02:14:00' startTime, '2019-06-06' endDate, '06:00:00' endTime

INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 'PERSON A' person, '2019-06-06' startDate, '22:00:00' startTime, '2019-06-07' endDate, '02:14:00' endTime

SELECT * FROM  @tbl;

with
  DateTimes as ( -- Assemble the   Date   and   Time   into   DateTime    values.
    select Cast( StartDate as DateTime ) + Cast( StartTime as DateTime ) as StartDT,
      Cast( EndDate as DateTime ) + Cast( EndTime as DateTime ) as EndDT
      from @tbl ),
  DeltaTimes as ( -- Calculate the number of seconds between   StartDT   and   EndDT.
    select DateDiff( second, StartDT, EndDT ) as Seconds
      from DateTimes ),
  TotalTime as ( -- Sum all of the periods.
    select Sum( Seconds ) as TotalTime
      from DeltaTimes )
  -- You can replace the final   select   statement with one of these to display the intermediate results.
  --select * from DateTimes;
  --select * from DeltaTimes;
  --select * from TotalTime;
  select Cast( TotalTime / 3600 as VarChar(6) ) +
    ':' + Right( '0' + Cast( TotalTime / 60 % 60 as VarChar(2) ), 2 ) +
    ':' + Right( '0' + Cast( TotalTime % 60 as VarChar(2) ), 2 ) as TotalTime
    from TotalTime;
```

Comment: OK thank you, you just give me an idea of how to resolve this, plus... there's no incorrect data, actually I'm taking info from two different sources, that's why you see I'm trying to limit the endTime of second-row example, to be more specific on what I needed.

Comment: I made some changes because the question was not clear.

Comment: @Steven (1) Your update should be a new question since it has only a passing similarity to the original question. (2) You provided sample data, but not the expected results. Then added the expected results without explanation. (3) It still doesn't make sense. If a shift is from `22:00` through `06:00` then `21:59` and `06:09` should be discarded as invalid times.

Comment: I can't discard those times as I need them to determine attendance kpi, so they still being valid times. I will post a new question, thank you for the advice and your time to answer it was help full.

Comment: Posted a new question for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56650802/9829961